# php: strpos for array function only working once on page

Tags: php, header, footer, strpos

I don't get it …

I'm using this function that I found on stackoverflow:

```
<?php 
  //strpos with array
  function strposa($haystack, $needles=array(), $offset=0) {
    $chr = array();
    foreach($needles as $needle) {
      $res = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset);
      if ($res !== false) $chr[$needle] = $res;
    }
    if(empty($chr)) return false;
    return min($chr);
  }
?>
```

In my about.php file I have this

```
<?php $body_classes = "page-about page-template"; ?>
<?php include_once('header.php'); ?>
<?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>
```

In my footer.php file I have this …

```
<footer id="footer" <?php if (strposa($body_classes , array('page-about'))) { echo "class='fixed'"; } ?> >
```

… which works just fine.

However in my header.php file I have the same code just for the header …

```
<header id="header" <?php if (strposa($body_classes , array('page-about'))) { echo "class='fixed'"; } ?> >
```

which doesn't work in the header file and I don't know why.

Why is my `fixed` class only applied in the footer file but not in the header? any ideas?

Comment: No errors? Is that function included before header.php ?

Comment: It's actually included in the header.php file … ```<?php include_once('assets/inc/functions.php'); ?>
<body class="<?php echo $body_classes; ?>">``` the body classes work in the body tag, but the function doesn't return true.

Comment: Can you post value of $body_classes  and assure that it is constant before both uses of that strposa function?